# What's the difference between Z-Wave and Z-Wave Plus?

Tags: zwave

What are the technical differences between Z-Wave and its Plus alternative? Is Plus just a stronger signal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Z-Wave Alliance have [a page explaining the differences](https://z-wavealliance.org/z-wave_plus_certification/) pretty nicely:

> Z-Wave Plus™ is a new certification program designed to help consumers identify products that take advantage of the recently introduced 'Next Gen' Z-Wave hardware platform, also know as 500 Series or 5th Generation Z-Wave. [...]
>
> With the introduction of the Next-Gen, Z-Wave 500 series hardware platforms, Z-Wave saw its ecosystem bolstered with new capabilities, including increased range, extended battery life, Over The Air upgrading (OTA), additional RF channels and more — all of which are fully backwards compatible with existing Z-Wave products. [...]
>
> **Features**
>
> - 50% improvement in battery life
> - 67% improvement in range
> - 250% more bandwidth
> - Three RF channels for improved noise immunity and higher bandwidth
> - New Plug-n-Play Network-wide Inclusion feature
> - Improved self-healing and fault tolerance with Explorer Frame feature
> - Standardized method for Over the Air firmware updates (OTA)
> - Improved product information capture for product certification database

Some miscellaneous differences are noted in a [TechHive report](https://www.techhive.com/article/2031180/sigma-designs-announces-next-gen-z-wave-home-control-product-family.html):

> The new chips also boast dramatically smaller packages. Sigma’s SD3502, for instance, is a general-purpose Z-Wave system-on-a-chip that integrates a microcontroller, RF transceiver, 128-bit AES security engine, and memory in a package that measures just 7mm square.

From the perspective of a consumer, Z-Wave Plus' main benefits are battery life and range. Many hubs (e.g. [SmartThings](https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115003226203-SmartThings-Hub-Miscellaneous-FAQ#zwaveplus)) already support Z-Wave Plus, and many sensors and other nodes support it too. The Z-Wave Alliance [claim](https://z-wavealliance.org/z-wave_plus_faq/) that Z-Wave Plus devices generally won't cost a lot more, either, so in that case, it's probably beneficial to pick Z-Wave Plus *if possible*.

As a developer, the OTA updates and smaller chip are likely to be useful. I can't say much about the technical details, because the [specifications](http://z-wave.sigmadesigns.com/design-z-wave/z-wave-quick-start-guide/) are secured and require the signature of a non-disclosure agreement. If anyone has any additional information, I'd be interested to hear.